# Not able to draw a full circle on canvas in JavaScript using mouse events

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I want to draw a simple circle on a canvas using mouse events, but what I am getting is partial circles, half circles, and sometimes a full one. The rectangle is working fine.Picture of resulting partial circles is attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pupd3.png)
Code is

```js
        function draw() {
                     if (circ == 1)
            {
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h, Math.PI * 2, false);
                context.stroke();
            }

        }

        function mouseDownrect(e) {
            rect.startX = (e.layerX - this.offsetLeft);
            rect.startY = e.layerY - this.offsetTop;
            drag = true;

        }

        function mouseUprect() {

            draw();
            rect.w = 0;
            rect.h = 0;
            drag = false;
        }

        function mouseMoverect(e) {

            if (drag == true) {
                rect.w = (e.layerX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
                rect.h = (e.layerY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
            }

        }
        function rectangle() {
            color = 'black';
            rectan = 1;
            circ = 0;
            pen = 0;
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownrect, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUprect, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoverect, false);

        }
        function Circle()
        {
            color = 'black';
            circ = 1;
            rectan = 0;
            pen = 0;
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownrect, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUprect, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoverect, false);
        }
```

Comment: You should look at the reference for [`arc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) the 4th argument is for an angle not height

Answer (score 0):

The fourth argument in arc() is the starting ANGLE. So you want 0 to Math.PI * 2 for a full circle.

context.arc(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);

Also, the 3rd argument is the RADIUS, and i don't know what you want that to be.